# Spel expression spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there a way to use `@Value` annotation for retrieving 2 property values and merging them as 1?

```
public void setPath(@Value("{#foo['base']+#foo['subdirectory']}) File file)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to spring [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html) you have got the

> .concat()

But I really do not know it it works...